# How to handling PDO MySQL fail over in AWS using persistent connections

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo, amazon-aurora

We have experienced a problem with AWS Aurora failover and looking for pointers as to how to resolve.

*Scenario*

AWS Aurora set up with two end points:

- Writer:

  - host: stackName-dbcluster-ID.cluster-ID.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  - resolves to IP: 10.1.0.X
- Reader:

  - host: stackName-dbcluster-ID.cluster-ro-ID.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  - resolves to IP: 10.1.0.Y

So therefore our PDO MySQL Connection string is `stackName-dbcluster-ID.cluster-ID.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` (for writing)

*After failover*

On failover, the DNS entries are flipped to point as follows:

- Reader:

  - host: stackName-dbcluster-ID.cluster-ro-ID.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  - resolves to IP: 10.1.0.X
- Writer:

  - host: stackName-dbcluster-ID.cluster-ID.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  - resolves to IP: 10.1.0.Y

Critically, the PDO Connection string (for writing) remains the same "stackName-dbcluster-ID.cluster-ID.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" b ut points to a different IP address.

**What Happened**

We had error 1290 "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1290 The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement".

As the DB engines are stopped started, our initial persistent connections will have "gone away" and been invalidated (something we immediately handle in a reconnect/retry code).

However the error above means new connections will have been made to the old node, but then not further invalidated with propagation of the DNS change. They lasted 10/15 minutes (well beyond TTL of the DNS).

**My Questions**

1. Does anyone know if a persistent connection on PDO is retrieved based on the connection string, or is more reliable using the IP or other signature? Evidence suggests it's hostname, but would like confirmation.
2. Does anyone know a way to mark a persistent connection as "invalid" in PDO, so that is it not used again?
3. Or, is there something I missed?

**Side notes**

We already have code in place to handle the retry, and they retry is told to get a new non-persistent connection (which works). It's at this point we could "invalidate" the PDO connection so the next run of a script does not repeat this cycle over and over.

The failover can happen at any time, so we're not in a position to do manual actions such as restart php (as we had to do this time).

Without persistent connections, performance is notably slower.

FastCGI, Centos 16, PHP 7.2, MySQLD 5.0.12-dev (which is normal on Centos - see https://superuser.com/questions/1433346/php-shows-outdated-mysqlnd-version)

Comment: Update: Have been reading about https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php - however it is unclear if using this plugin will resolve the same issue. It may help with fail over, but unclear if a DNS change will allow invalidation of existing connections. Any confirmation/pointers appreciated.

Comment: Two individual servers won't provide the same availability as a [NBD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster.html) or [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-userguide.html) cluster would provide.

Comment: Not an actual answer, but note that you can in fact restart php on failover. Or do something else. You can subscribe to [RDS events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html), which could enable you to work around the issue. Far from ideal, but maybe it helps.

Comment: @bgdnlp thanks for the comment. As noted in question, I did restart PHP after our alarm system went nuts (we have about 500 monitoring points per installation), But I'd rather everything self-fix before errors happen, than need to be woken because we have errors triggering alarms. The failover would alert anyway, but we can relax as opposed to worry...

Comment: can check if it work for you : https://github.com/jeremydaly/serverless-mysql/issues/7

Comment: @walternuñez Thanks - yes, appears the same problem and appears to be suggesting changes at the driver level. I could swap the mysqlnd driver for mysqlnd_ms that _might_ have a solution, but as that's a big risk and might not work, that's why I'm posting here to see if anyone else has ever had the same problem.

Comment: DNS lookup in this situation is not reliable. Use static IP addresses in this case.

Comment: @Robbie can you check if anyone of this utility help youo to solve the handly failover in AWS: but work over MySQL http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql/replication-and-auto-failover-made-easy-with-mysql-utilities

Comment: @dilyan - if we used IP addresses, then we'd always be pointing at the now-defunct database, and even the partial solution we have would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent connections must be terminated and restarted.

Reminds me of a 2-minute TTL that took 20 minutes to be recognized.  I don't know whether Amazon does a better job, or even if they have any say in DNS.

5.0.12??  That was released in 2005!  Maybe a typo.  Anyway, I don't think the version matters in this Question.

DNS may not be the optimal way to failover; there are several Proxy servers out there.  I would expect them to flip within seconds.  However, they need to know who's who rather than depending on DNS.

Can you modify the code to disconnect+reconnect when that error occurs?  (It may not help.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned in the question, the code does disconnect and reconnect using a non-persistence connection and this solves the issue *for that single instance of script*. The problem is that the next script comes along and grabs a persistent connection that is *still* pointing to the old server and has to repeat the disconnect/reconnect sequence. Thousands and thousands of times. I need to know how to invalidate that persistent connection.

Comment: Regarding DNS not being the optimal way / proxies, this is how AWS works. There is that mysqlnd_ms library I mention in a comment, but I see no logic that suggests it won't suffer the same issue. I'll try if there are no alternatives others can suggest.

Comment: @Robbie - How many persistent connections is it configured for?  It might help to lower that?

Comment: I didn't know you can set the maximum number, and the manual page doesn't appear to have a config: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.config.php (or is it somewhere else?). We have up to 80 FPM processes running off a variable number of apache processes. Very roughtly there are about 1000 connections per server. While reducing them might reduce the problem, it won't remove the problem (which is what I'd like to do!)

Comment: @Robbie - Apache has a way to control the number of children it spawns (in "mpm"?).  The drastic approach to "removing the problem" may be to restart Apache.

Comment: I can see you're thinking is similar to mine! We already set both the number of apache children and FPM children to suit the application load. So reducing may impact load, but still won't remove the problem. As noted in question, we did the restart this time (all three services (apache, fpm and DNS) - drastic, but it's a guaranteed fix and it was middle of the night). What I'm looking for is the automated way so I don't get alarms in the night - which I think is by telling a persistent connection it's now invalid and to close.

Comment: Midnight alarms are no fun.  So I am fishing for how to _prevent_ them (as opposed to deal with them).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this error is documented:

https://github.com/jeremydaly/serverless-mysql/issues/7

everything said revolves around migrating to: `mysqlnd` driver for `mysqlnd_ms`

I will continue looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Nowhere do I mention serverless in the question. I'm the one that mentioned the difference in drivers - they are not mentioned in that link (or anywhere else, actually - I'm looking to see if someone else has experienced it). Thanks all in the comments above. This is a blatant answer to try to grab bounty points - please delete it.

Comment: Check this: http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql/replication-and-auto-failover-made-easy-with-mysql-utilities

Comment: I did. I read through that entire page and there was absolutely no reference to the issue at hand. Can you add to your answer the relevant part because it's shooting right over my head.